# In android can we create our own analog clock?

Tags: android

I am new to android application development. I want to create an application which shows an analog clock, but i should not use predefined analog clock class. If anybody know this please help me.

Thanks,
Yugandhar

Comment: check out official documentation at developer.android.com and search for similar questions here first.

Answer (score 9):

Yes we can create the analog clock my self. Below is the sample code and link for full project http://code.google.com/p/android-analog-clock/

```
public class AnalogClock1 extends View {
    public AnalogClock1(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private Time mCalendar;

    private Drawable mHourHand;
    private Drawable mMinuteHand;
    private Drawable mSecondHand;
    private Drawable mDial;

    private int mDialWidth;
    private int mDialHeight;

    private boolean mAttached;

    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private float mMinutes;
    private float mHour;
    private boolean mChanged;


Context mContext;
    public AnalogClock1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public AnalogClock1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                       int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        Resources r = context.getResources();
        TypedArray a =
                context.obtainStyledAttributes(
                        attrs, R.styleable.AnalogClock, defStyle, 0);
        mContext=context;
       // mDial = a.getDrawable(com.android.internal.R.styleable.AnalogClock_dial);
       // if (mDial == null) {
            mDial = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.clock_dial);
       // }

      //  mHourHand = a.getDrawable(com.android.internal.R.styleable.AnalogClock_hand_hour);
      //  if (mHourHand == null) {
            mHourHand = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.clock_hour);
      //  }

     //   mMinuteHand = a.getDrawable(com.android.internal.R.styleable.AnalogClock_hand_minute);
     //   if (mMinuteHand == null) {
            mMinuteHand = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.clock_minute);
            mSecondHand = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.clockgoog_minute);
     //   }

        mCalendar = new Time();

        mDialWidth = mDial.getIntrinsicWidth();
        mDialHeight = mDial.getIntrinsicHeight();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        if (!mAttached) {
            mAttached = true;
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);

          getContext().registerReceiver(mIntentReceiver, filter, null, mHandler);
        }

        // NOTE: It's safe to do these after registering the receiver since the receiver always runs
        // in the main thread, therefore the receiver can't run before this method returns.

        // The time zone may have changed while the receiver wasn't registered, so update the Time
        mCalendar = new Time();

        // Make sure we update to the current time
        onTimeChanged();
        counter.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        if (mAttached) {
            counter.cancel();
           getContext().unregisterReceiver(mIntentReceiver);
            mAttached = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int widthSize =  MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize =  MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        float hScale = 1.0f;
        float vScale = 1.0f;

        if (widthMode != MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED && widthSize < mDialWidth) {
            hScale = (float) widthSize / (float) mDialWidth;
        }

        if (heightMode != MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED && heightSize < mDialHeight) {
            vScale = (float )heightSize / (float) mDialHeight;
        }

        float scale = Math.min(hScale, vScale);

        setMeasuredDimension(resolveSize((int) (mDialWidth * scale), widthMeasureSpec),
                resolveSize((int) (mDialHeight * scale), heightMeasureSpec));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mChanged = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        boolean changed = mChanged;
        if (changed) {
            mChanged = false;
        }
        boolean seconds = mSeconds;
        if (seconds ) {
            mSeconds = false;
        }
        int availableWidth = 200;
        int availableHeight = 200;

        int x = availableWidth / 2;
        int y = availableHeight / 2;

        final Drawable dial = mDial;
        int w = dial.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int h = dial.getIntrinsicHeight();

        boolean scaled = false;

        if (availableWidth < w || availableHeight < h) {
            scaled = true;
            float scale = Math.min((float) availableWidth / (float) w,
                                   (float) availableHeight / (float) h);
            canvas.save();
            canvas.scale(scale, scale, x, y);
        }

        if (changed) {
            dial.setBounds(x - (w / 2), y - (h / 2), x + (w / 2), y + (h / 2));
        }
        dial.draw(canvas);

        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(mHour / 12.0f * 360.0f, x, y);
        final Drawable hourHand = mHourHand;
        if (changed) {
            w = hourHand.getIntrinsicWidth();
            h = hourHand.getIntrinsicHeight();
            hourHand.setBounds(x - (w / 2), y - (h / 2), x + (w / 2), y + (h / 2));
        }
        hourHand.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();

        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(mMinutes / 60.0f * 360.0f, x, y);
        //canvas.rotate(mSecond, x, y);
        final Drawable minuteHand = mMinuteHand;
        if (changed) {
            w = minuteHand.getIntrinsicWidth();
            h = minuteHand.getIntrinsicHeight();
            minuteHand.setBounds(x - (w / 2), y - (h / 2), x + (w / 2), y + (h / 2));
        }
        minuteHand.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
       canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(mSecond, x, y);

        //minuteHand = mMinuteHand;
        if (seconds) {
            w = mSecondHand.getIntrinsicWidth();
            h = mSecondHand.getIntrinsicHeight();
            mSecondHand.setBounds(x - (w / 2), y - (h / 2), x + (w / 2), y + (h / 2));
        }
        mSecondHand.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
        if (scaled) {
            canvas.restore();
        }
    }
    MyCount counter = new MyCount(10000, 1000);
    public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{
        public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            counter.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mCalendar.setToNow();

            int hour = mCalendar.hour;
            int minute = mCalendar.minute;
            int second = mCalendar.second;

              mSecond=6.0f*second;
            mSeconds=true;
             //mChanged = true;
             AnalogClock1.this.invalidate();
             //Toast.makeText(mContext, "text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
 }
boolean mSeconds=false;
float mSecond=0;
    private void onTimeChanged() {
        mCalendar.setToNow();

        int hour = mCalendar.hour;
        int minute = mCalendar.minute;
        int second = mCalendar.second;

        mMinutes = minute + second / 60.0f;
        mHour = hour + mMinutes / 60.0f;
        mChanged = true;
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED)) {
                String tz = intent.getStringExtra("time-zone");
                mCalendar = new Time(TimeZone.getTimeZone(tz).getID());
            }

            onTimeChanged();

            invalidate();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: sorry, but this grossly does not work. sure, it renders OK, but never updates. your code also references internal android resources, unavailable to app developers.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. Remember, Android is open source, so what I encourage you to do is look at [`their implementation of AnalogClock`](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/AnalogClock.java&q=package%3aandroid.git.kernel.org%20file%3aandroid/widget/AnalogClock.java) and see how they've done it. Then, you can build your own from scratch.