# Change Dial drawable of Android Analog Clock dynamically[programmatically]

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am new to android programming and seem to stumble upon this problem for some time now, i have used android analog clock widget as standard widget for my clock app and used custom dials and hand as it was possible, but now the requirement has changed to give further dials and design for the clock, i was searching here and there but cant seem to grasp this.

Can i change the default attribute of analog clock of dial, minute hand and hour hand programmatically in the code? like is there something like:

```
AnalogClock ac = (AnalogClock) findViewById(R.id.analogClock1);
ac.setDial(R.drawable.clock_dial_2);
```

i did this and this is not possible, is there any other method or methodology that i am missing??

Answer (score 0):

The stock widget doesn't seem to offer many customization methods. I think you're going to have to extend a View and code your own. It will go faster than you think and offer ultimate flexibility. Your client can customize to his/her heart's content. There's a start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149253/in-android-can-we-create-our-own-analog-clock).

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, believe it or not i found the same thing and did this in the meanwhile after posting this question, but the problem now is that when i use this in my widget, i get an error and now i get 'problem loading widget' instead of widget